# Страница не отвечает при нажатии утвердить

Tags: javascript

js:

```
let rmenu=document.getElementsByClassName('goods-item');
let btn_1=document.getElementsByTagName('button')[1];
let lmenu_14=document.getElementsByClassName('goods-value')[0];

btn_1.addEventListener('click',() => {
    for (let i=0; i < rmenu.length; i++) {
        let a=rmenu[i].value
            if ((typeof(a))==='string' && (typeof(a))===null && a.length < 50) {
                console.log ("всё верно!")
                mainlist.shopgoods=a;
                lmenu_14.textContent = mainlist.shopgoods;
            } else 
            {
            }
        }

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="main-functions">
            <div class="choose-goods">Введите категории товаров</div>
            <input class="goods-item" type="text" id="goods_1">
            <input class="goods-item" type="text" id="goods_2">
            <input class="goods-item" type="text" id="goods_3">
            <input class="goods-item" type="text" id="goods_4">
            <button class="goods-item-btn">Утвердить</button>
```

Comment: А что такое btn_1?

Comment: `i=i-1;` это дает бесконечный цикл?

Comment: походу да ,насчёт кнопок сейчас обновлю

Comment: Вы бы хоть указали какая ошибка валится или что происходит при нажатии. И почему в цикле i-1?

Comment: i=i-1 можно уже не считать ошибка при i-1 просто страница вылетает походу из-за бесконечного цикла а так просто ничего не происходит. А мне надо чтобы заполнялась форма которая lmenu_14.

Comment: если надо отправлю полностью html код

Answer (score 0):

ошибка была в условии,вот верное условие:

```
btn_1.addEventListener('click',() => {
    for (let i=0; i < rmenu.length; i++) {
        let a=rmenu[i].value
            if ((typeof(a))==='string' &&  a.length < 50) {
                console.log ("всё верно!")
                mainlist.shopgoods=a;
                lmenu_14.textContent = mainlist.shopgoods;
            } else 
            {

            }
        }
```